# Setting parent key but not child key while using endpoint-proto-datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

How can I set a parent/ancestor for an EndpointsModel and have the entity ID/Key generated automatically by datastore?

I've tried to adapt the [keys_with_ancestors](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/keys_with_ancestors.html) sample but seem to be hitting a bit of a block because it requires both id and parent to be specified. I'd like to do something similar except provide only parent id or key and have entity id/key auto-generated by the app engine datastore.

This following shows how I would do it using just NDB.

```
class Parent(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    attr1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    attr2 = ndb.StringProperty()

p = Parent(name="Jerry")
p_key = p.put()  # or retrieve the key from somewhere else

mod = MyModel(parent=p_key)
mod.put()
```

Is this possible and could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the [keys_with_ancestors](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/keys_with_ancestors.html) sample, let's assume we have the same imports and have defined the class `MyParent` in the same way it is defined there.

The TL;DR answer is essentially that passing `parent=` to the model constructor is equivalent to creating a key with `None` as the last ID in the list of kind, ID pairs. For example, for a class `MyModel`:

```
>>> parent = ndb.Key(MyModel, 1)
>>> child = MyModel(parent=parent)
>>> print child.key
ndb.Key('MyModel', 1, 'MyModel', None)
```

In order to do this with the sample, we could simply ignore the `id`:

```
class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
  _parent = None

  attr1 = ndb.StringProperty()
  attr2 = ndb.StringProperty()
  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

and in the setter simply set the half-baked key and don't try to retrieve from the datastore (since the key is not complete):

```
  def ParentSet(self, value):
    if not isinstance(value, basestring):
      raise TypeError('Parent name must be a string.')

    self._parent = value
    if ndb.Key(MyParent, value).get() is None:
      raise endpoints.NotFoundException('Parent %s does not exist.' % value)
    self.key = ndb.Key(MyParent, self._parent, MyModel, None)

    self._endpoints_query_info.ancestor = ndb.Key(MyParent, value)
```

Similarly, in the getter, you can just retrieve the parent directly from the key (though this doesn't guarantee there is only a single pair as the parent):

```
  @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=ParentSet, required=True)
  def parent(self):
    if self._parent is None and self.key is not None:
      self._parent = self.key.parent().string_id()
    return self._parent
```

Having done this you won't need to change any of the API code and the example will work as expected.

Comment: Awesome. Not setting MyModel ID to None was where I came unstuck. Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense now.

Comment: How would you do the simple get for MyModel? I''m trying path='mymodels/{parent}/{id} but getting 404. Thanks.

Comment: @Rastio You need to call to UpdateFromKey function with the new key before calling the from_datastore property:

`mymodel.UpdateFromKey(ndb.Key('MyParent', mymodel.parent, 'MyModel', mymodel.key.id()))

    if not mymodel.from_datastore:
      raise endpoints.NotFoundException('MyModel not found.')
    return mymodel`